# How to add a slow motion effect to my player?

Tags: android, animation, libgdx, game-physics, motion

I want to move my player in slow motion to the right and to the left. I can move my player, but it isn't look cool. I want to see slow motion when the player moves. How can I do this?

My Player is going through to y axis. I have 2 buttons to left and to right for movement.

I can move the player to the direct position, but I want to use slow motion.

PlayScreen:
[image: this is my PlayScreen screenshot]

```
public float speed = 0.09f;

 buttonimage.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
        {

            player.position.x -= 300 * speed;



            return true;
        }
    });
```

my render method

```
public void render(float delta) {


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



    player.position.y += 500 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(bg, 0, camera.position.y - (camera.viewportHeight/2));
    sb.draw(player.texture, player.getPosition().x , player.getPosition().y);
    for (Tube tube : tubes) {
        sb.draw(tube.getlefttube(), tube.getposlefttube().x, tube.getposlefttube().y);
        sb.draw(tube.getrighttube(), tube.getposrighttube().x, tube.getposrighttube().y);
        sb.draw(tube.getLight() , tube.getPoslight().x , tube.getPoslight().y);
    }





    delta*=speed;
    sb.end();
    update(delta);

    stage.draw();


    app.batch.begin();
    app.font23.draw(app.batch,"Lights collected :" + dropsGathered , 0, 720);
    app.batch.end();


}
```

Comment: But what do you mean by slow motion? Slow relative to what? I don't see the player moving horizontally at all in your render method.

Comment: I mean my player have to move to the left slow when the button is pressed.

Comment: now in my codes , my player directs to the 300*speed to left. I wanna see my player moves in slow motion.

Comment: So just use a number smaller than 300. I must not be understanding the question because it seems too simple. But if you want to move the player continuously while pressing the button, you need to set a boolean in touchDown and use the boolean to decide whether to move the player in render.

Comment: I dont want to move player continuously while pressing the button. I've tried setting a number smaller than 300. but it moves smaller to the left. it is useless.

Comment: You want your player to move 300*speed in slow motion without being between those two points? This is not possible.
aret you are saying that you want to move player to a certain point regardless of how long the screen is pressed?

Comment: I guess I need to use box2d. I'm looking for it now. what I want is , I will touch my leftbuttonimage and my player will move to the left in slow motion.

Answer (score 0):

I can just tell you how I would do that, using [Box2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d#impulsesforces)

Example from this page:

```
// apply right impulse, but only if max velocity is not reached yet
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D) && vel.x < MAX_VELOCITY) {
     this.player.body.applyLinearImpulse(0.80f, 0, pos.x, pos.y, true);
}
```

Then you can draw your sprites relative to the player.body

Comment: if I do this , my body will move but not my player. how can I attach my player to my body for moving

Comment: I have no idea how your player looks like, but maybe you have to create a new player class which inherits from player: `class MyPlayer extends Player`. Then you override the render and draw method from MyPlayer at the position of body